# dpkg: error processing archive

Tags: package-management, dependencies

I am new to Ubuntu, when I try to install new package, It is asking for run `sudo apt-get -f install` command, and when I execute that command, I am getting following logs:

```
temp@temp-desktop:~$ sudo apt-get -f install
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... Done
The following extra packages will be installed:
  libgcrypt11
Suggested packages:
  rng-tools
The following packages will be upgraded:
  libgcrypt11
1 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 288 not upgraded.
13 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/239 kB of archives.
After this operation, 1,024 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] Y
(Reading database ... 199052 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../libgcrypt11_1.5.3-2ubuntu4.2_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libgcrypt11:amd64 (1.5.3-2ubuntu4.2) over (1.5.0-3ubuntu2.1) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/libgcrypt11_1.5.3-2ubuntu4.2_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite shared '/usr/share/doc/libgcrypt11/changelog.Debian.gz', which is different from other instances of package libgcrypt11:amd64
dpkg-deb: error: subprocess paste was killed by signal (Broken pipe)
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/libgcrypt11_1.5.3-2ubuntu4.2_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Any help will be appreciated.
Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can fix the error by:

```
sudo rm /usr/share/doc/libgcrypt11/*
```

Then do:

```
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

Comment: I have to run `sudo rm /usr/share/doc/libgcrypt11/*` Thanks for help.